# Unable to connect to Siteground hosted Mail from work but can from home and tethered

Tags: email

This is really stumping us in our office.  Recently we have been unable to connect to our Siteground hosted email across all platforms and devices from our office network (static IP address).  This seems to be intermittent in that yesterday we were unable to connect, this morning we could and a few hours later we are unable to. (Normal internet traffic is fine)

However outside of the office we are able to.  Both Siteground and the ISP tell us that they are not blocking any ports or IP. How can we determine where the block is occuring?

Comment: Have you run a tracert? Anything fishy in your hosts file?

Comment: This must be some firewall somewhere. tracert is a good idea : note the address after which it blocked, and compare it with the route when access is possible. The weak part is that there is no guarantee that the same route will be used twice. Try also `ping` when blocked.